# Stochastically increasing random variables have continuous distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose that $(X_\alpha)_{\alpha >0}$ is a family of random variables supported on $\{0,1,2,\cdots\}$ with the properties (i) $E X_\alpha = \alpha$ and (ii) $X_\alpha \preceq X_\alpha'$ whenever $\alpha \leq \alpha'$ in the usual sense of stochastic domination $P(X_\alpha > a) \leq P(X_{\alpha'} >a)$ for all $a\geq 0$.

Is it true that the functions $p_k(\alpha)= P(X_\alpha = k)$ are continuous in $\alpha$?

Answer (score 3):

Let $\alpha' < \alpha$. We have from (i) that

$$E X_\alpha - E X_{\alpha'} = \alpha - \alpha' = \sum_{m=0}^\infty [P(X_\alpha > m) - P(X_{\alpha'} >m)].$$
By (ii) we know that each summand $P(X_\alpha > m) - P(X_{\alpha'} >m)$ is positive.

It follows that $P(X_\alpha > m) - P(X_{\alpha'} >m) \leq \alpha - \alpha'$ which can be made arbitrarily small. Thus, $P(X_\alpha > m)$ is continuous for all $m\geq 0$, which applied iteratively to the quantities $P(X_\alpha \leq m) = \sum_{k=0}^m P(X_\alpha = k)$ implies that the $P(X_\alpha=k)$ are continuous.